# Does the Enum#values() allocate memory on each call?

Tags: java, memory-management, enums

I need to convert an ordinal `int` value to an enum value in Java. Which is simple:

```
MyEnumType value = MyEnumType.values()[ordinal];
```

The `values()` method is implicit, and I cannot locate the source code for it, hence the question.

Does the `MyEnumType.values()` allocate a new array or not? And if it does, should I cache the array when first called? Suppose that the conversion will be called quite often.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes.

Java doesn't have mechanism which lets us create unmodifiable array. So if `values()` would return same mutable array, we risk that someone could change its content for everyone.

So until unmodifiable arrays will be introduced to Java, for safety `values()` must return new/separate array holding all values.

We can test it with `==` operator:

```
MyEnumType[] arr1 = MyEnumType.values();
MyEnumType[] arr2 = MyEnumType.values();
System.out.println(arr1 == arr2);       //false
```

---

If you want to avoid recreating this array you can simply store it and reuse result of `values()` later. There are few ways to do it, like.

- you can create private array and allow access to its content only via getter method like

  ```
  private static final MyEnumType[] VALUES = values();// to avoid recreating array

  MyEnumType getByOrdinal(int){
      return VALUES[int];
  }
  ```
- you can store result of `values()` in unmodifiable collection like `List` to ensure that its content will not be changed (now such list can be public).

  ```
  public static final List<MyEnumType> VALUES = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(values()));
  ```

Comment: Oh, and for the reasoning about this, it's for safety - if it returned the same array every time, someone could change the contents and you'd then see the changed array, not the original and correct one.

Comment: "You can test it simply with == operator" that only shows that your particular Java implementation creates a new array each time. It does not indicate that it *must* do so.

Answer (score 17):

Theoretically, the `values()` method must return a new array every time, since Java doesn't have immutable arrays. If it always returned the same array it could not prevent callers muddling each other up by modifying the array.

> I cannot locate the source code for it

The `values()` method has no ordinary source code, being compiler-generated. For javac, the code that generates the `values()` method is in [com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Lower.visitEnumDef](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/langtools/file/f166261986cc/src/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/comp/Lower.java#l2546). For ECJ (Eclipse's compiler), the code is in  [org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.codegen.CodeStream.generateSyntheticBodyForEnumValues](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/4.4.2/org.eclipse.jdt/core/3.10.2/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/codegen/CodeStream.java#2787).

An easier way to find the implementation of the `values()` method is by disassembling a compiled enum. First create some silly enum:

```
enum MyEnumType {
    A, B, C;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(values()[0]);
    }
}
```

Then compile it, and disassemble it using the javap tool included in the JDK:

```
javac MyEnumType.java && javap -c -p MyEnumType
```

Visible in the output are all the compiler-generated implicit members of the enum, including (1) a `static final` field for each enum constant, (2) a hidden `$VALUES` array containing all the constants, (3) a static initializer block that instantiates each constant and assigns each one to its named field and to the array, and (4) the `values()` method that works by calling `.clone()` on the `$VALUES` array and returning the result:

```
final class MyEnumType extends java.lang.Enum<MyEnumType> {
  public static final MyEnumType A;

  public static final MyEnumType B;

  public static final MyEnumType C;

  private static final MyEnumType[] $VALUES;

  public static MyEnumType[] values();
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #1                  // Field $VALUES:[LMyEnumType;
       3: invokevirtual #2                  // Method "[LMyEnumType;".clone:()Ljava/lang/Object;
       6: checkcast     #3                  // class "[LMyEnumType;"
       9: areturn

  public static MyEnumType valueOf(java.lang.String);
    Code:
       0: ldc           #4                  // class MyEnumType
       2: aload_0
       3: invokestatic  #5                  // Method java/lang/Enum.valueOf:(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Enum;
       6: checkcast     #4                  // class MyEnumType
       9: areturn

  private MyEnumType(java.lang.String, int);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: aload_1
       2: iload_2
       3: invokespecial #6                  // Method java/lang/Enum."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
       6: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #7                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: invokestatic  #8                  // Method values:()[LMyEnumType;
       6: iconst_0
       7: aaload
       8: invokevirtual #9                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
      11: return

  static {};
    Code:
       0: new           #4                  // class MyEnumType
       3: dup
       4: ldc           #10                 // String A
       6: iconst_0
       7: invokespecial #11                 // Method "<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
      10: putstatic     #12                 // Field A:LMyEnumType;
      13: new           #4                  // class MyEnumType
      16: dup
      17: ldc           #13                 // String B
      19: iconst_1
      20: invokespecial #11                 // Method "<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
      23: putstatic     #14                 // Field B:LMyEnumType;
      26: new           #4                  // class MyEnumType
      29: dup
      30: ldc           #15                 // String C
      32: iconst_2
      33: invokespecial #11                 // Method "<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
      36: putstatic     #16                 // Field C:LMyEnumType;
      39: iconst_3
      40: anewarray     #4                  // class MyEnumType
      43: dup
      44: iconst_0
      45: getstatic     #12                 // Field A:LMyEnumType;
      48: aastore
      49: dup
      50: iconst_1
      51: getstatic     #14                 // Field B:LMyEnumType;
      54: aastore
      55: dup
      56: iconst_2
      57: getstatic     #16                 // Field C:LMyEnumType;
      60: aastore
      61: putstatic     #1                  // Field $VALUES:[LMyEnumType;
      64: return
}
```

*However*, the fact that the `values()` method has to return a new array, doesn't mean the compiler has to use the method. Potentially a compiler could detect use of `MyEnumType.values()[ordinal]` and, seeing that the array is not modified, it could bypass the method and use the underlying `$VALUES` array. The above disassembly of the `main` method shows that javac does *not* make such an optimization.

I also tested ECJ. The disassembly shows ECJ also initializes a hidden array to store the constants (although the Java langspec doesn't require that), but interestingly its `values()` method prefers to create a blank array then fill it with `System.arraycopy`, rather than calling `.clone()`. Either way, `values()` returns a new array every time. Like javac, it doesn't attempt to optimize the ordinal lookup:

```
final class MyEnumType extends java.lang.Enum<MyEnumType> {
  public static final MyEnumType A;

  public static final MyEnumType B;

  public static final MyEnumType C;

  private static final MyEnumType[] ENUM$VALUES;

  static {};
    Code:
       0: new           #1                  // class MyEnumType
       3: dup
       4: ldc           #14                 // String A
       6: iconst_0
       7: invokespecial #15                 // Method "<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
      10: putstatic     #19                 // Field A:LMyEnumType;
      13: new           #1                  // class MyEnumType
      16: dup
      17: ldc           #21                 // String B
      19: iconst_1
      20: invokespecial #15                 // Method "<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
      23: putstatic     #22                 // Field B:LMyEnumType;
      26: new           #1                  // class MyEnumType
      29: dup
      30: ldc           #24                 // String C
      32: iconst_2
      33: invokespecial #15                 // Method "<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
      36: putstatic     #25                 // Field C:LMyEnumType;
      39: iconst_3
      40: anewarray     #1                  // class MyEnumType
      43: dup
      44: iconst_0
      45: getstatic     #19                 // Field A:LMyEnumType;
      48: aastore
      49: dup
      50: iconst_1
      51: getstatic     #22                 // Field B:LMyEnumType;
      54: aastore
      55: dup
      56: iconst_2
      57: getstatic     #25                 // Field C:LMyEnumType;
      60: aastore
      61: putstatic     #27                 // Field ENUM$VALUES:[LMyEnumType;
      64: return

  private MyEnumType(java.lang.String, int);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: aload_1
       2: iload_2
       3: invokespecial #31                 // Method java/lang/Enum."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
       6: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #35                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: invokestatic  #41                 // Method values:()[LMyEnumType;
       6: iconst_0
       7: aaload
       8: invokevirtual #45                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
      11: return

  public static MyEnumType[] values();
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #27                 // Field ENUM$VALUES:[LMyEnumType;
       3: dup
       4: astore_0
       5: iconst_0
       6: aload_0
       7: arraylength
       8: dup
       9: istore_1
      10: anewarray     #1                  // class MyEnumType
      13: dup
      14: astore_2
      15: iconst_0
      16: iload_1
      17: invokestatic  #53                 // Method java/lang/System.arraycopy:(Ljava/lang/Object;ILjava/lang/Object;II)V
      20: aload_2
      21: areturn

  public static MyEnumType valueOf(java.lang.String);
    Code:
       0: ldc           #1                  // class MyEnumType
       2: aload_0
       3: invokestatic  #59                 // Method java/lang/Enum.valueOf:(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Enum;
       6: checkcast     #1                  // class MyEnumType
       9: areturn
}
```

*However*, it's still potentially possible that the JVM could have an optimization that detects the fact that the array is copied and then thrown away, and avoids it. To test that, I ran the following pair of benchmark programs that test ordinal lookup in a loop, one which calls `values()` each time and the other that uses a private copy of the array. The result of the ordinal lookup is assigned to a `volatile` field to prevent it being optimized away:

```
enum MyEnumType1 {
    A, B, C;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long t = System.nanoTime();
        for (int n = 0; n < 100_000_000; n++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                dummy = values()[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("Done in %.2f seconds.\n", (System.nanoTime() - t) / 1e9);
    }

    public static volatile Object dummy;
}

enum MyEnumType2 {
    A, B, C;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long t = System.nanoTime();
        for (int n = 0; n < 100_000_000; n++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                dummy = values[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("Done in %.2f seconds.\n", (System.nanoTime() - t) / 1e9);
    }

    public static volatile Object dummy;
    private static final MyEnumType2[] values = values();
}
```

I ran this on Java 8u60, on the Server VM. Each test using the `values()` method took around 10 seconds, while each test using the private array took around 2 seconds. Using the `-verbose:gc` JVM argument showed there was significant garbage collection activity when the `values()` method was used, and none when using the private array. Running the same tests on the Client VM, the private array was still fast, but the `values()` method became even slower, taking over a minute to finish. Calling `values()` also took longer the more enum constants were defined. All this indicates that the `values()` method really does allocate a new array each time, and that avoiding it can be advantageous.

Note that both [`java.util.EnumSet`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/7d1d5f4d019a/src/share/classes/java/util/EnumSet.java) and [`java.util.EnumMap`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/7d1d5f4d019a/src/share/classes/java/util/EnumMap.java) need to use the array of enum constants. For performance they call JRE proprietary code that caches the result of `values()` [in a shared array](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/7d1d5f4d019a/src/share/classes/java/lang/Class.java#l3301) stored in `java.lang.Class`. You can get access to that shared array yourself by calling `sun.misc.SharedSecrets.getJavaLangAccess().getEnumConstantsShared(MyEnumType.class)`, but it is unsafe to depend on it as such APIs are not part of any spec and can be changed or removed in any Java update.

Conclusion:

- The enum `values()` method has to behave as if it always allocates a new array, in case callers modify it.
- Compilers or VMs could potentially optimize that allocation away in some cases, but apparently they don't.
- In performance-critical code, it is well worth taking your own copy of the array.